# How to implement a (more complex) R plyr chain in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to implement the following plyr chain in python:

```
# Data
data_L1

X Y r2  contact_id acknowledge_issues
a c 100 xyzx       0
b d 100 fsdjkfl    0
a c 80  ejrkl      20
b d 60  fdsdl      40
b d 80  gsdkf      20

# Transformation
test <- ddply(data_L1,
              .(X,Y),
              summarize,
              avg_r2 = mean(r2),
              tickets = length(unique(contact_id)),
              er_ai =length(acknowledge_issues[which(acknowledge_issues>0)])/length(acknowledge_issues)
              )

# Output
test

X Y avg_r2 tickets er_ai
a c 90     2       0.5
b d 80     3       0.6667
```

However I only came this far in python:

```
test = data_L1.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'r2': 'mean', 'contact_id' : 'count'})
```

I can't figure out how to create the variables er_ai in Python. Do you have suggestions for solutions in pandas or other libraries?

Comment: Do you need `test = data_L1.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'r2': 'mean', 'contact_id' : 'nunique', 'acknowledge_issues': lambda x: (x>0).mean()})` ?

Comment: and then `test = test.rename(columns={'r2':'avg_r2', 'contact_id':'tickets', 'acknowledge_issues':'er_ai'})` ?

Comment: edited! for er_ai I would need: count number of entries which are >0 and divide by number of all entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead `count` function [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and for `er_ai` get `mean` of all values by condition:

```
cols = {'r2':'avg_r2', 'contact_id':'tickets', 'acknowledge_issues':'er_ai'}
test = (data_L1.groupby(['X','Y'], as_index=False)
               .agg({'r2': 'mean', 
                     'contact_id' : 'nunique', 
                     'acknowledge_issues': lambda x: (x>0).mean()})
               .rename(columns=cols))
print (test)
   X  Y  tickets     er_ai  avg_r2
0  a  c        2  0.500000      90
1  b  d        3  0.666667      80
```

Comment: that works thanks! but why does `(x>0).mean()` make `length(acknowledge_issues[which(acknowledge_issues>0)])/length(acknowledge_issues)`?

Comment: because if filter `x>0` get output `True+False` array. For get all Trues need `(x>0).sum()`, so `(x>0).sum() / len(x)` is same as `(x>0).mean()`